# Manual Trigger on Input[type=“file”] doesn't work on ios 12.2

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ios12

In my app, I was triggering to choose files from Files app of iPhone.
It was working till 12.1 but after updating iOS to 12.2, it is not working.

Here is my code -

```
// Create input element and trigger click
var input = $(document.createElement("input"));
input.attr("type", "file");
input.attr("accept", "*");
input.trigger("click");// opening dialog
```

Note - It works if I simply make input like-

```
<input type="file" accept="*">
```

Comment: Similar issue discussed here. https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1766

Comment: I was just going through it to find solution of it and got a use case-
It is working on iOS Simulator 12.2 and not working on actual device with iOS12.2 .

Comment: If this is a version issue, please raise a bug ticket.

Comment: Yeah @MebinJoe, Reported Bug to apple also...

Comment: Are you using fastclick? We saw a similar issue, it was resolved by turning fastclick off.

Comment: No @1800INFORMATION, I am not using fastclick & Not anything like this.
Were you also facing problem in specific version of iOS (v12.2) ?

Comment: yes we saw this problem in iOS 12.2 only. We resolved it by turning off fastclick on this element.

Comment: Thanks for info @1800INFORMATION. It may help others.